# String operation in ruby for credit card number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, credit-card, activemerchant

Working on a rails project where there's an order confirmation string with a credit card number with all but the last four digits starred out. What's the proper way to do a string substitution?

What's the operation to get this

```
credit_card_number = "1111111111111111"
```

to this?

```
credit_card_number = "************1111"
```

Thanks,

Kenji

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using ActiveMerchant, `ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard` has an instance method called `display_number` which does this e.g. XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-4338

If you're not, copy activemerchant:

```
def last_digits(number)    
  number.to_s.length <= 4 ? number : number.to_s.slice(-4..-1) 
end

def mask(number)
 "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-#{last_digits(number)}"
end

credit_card_number = "1111111111111111"

display_number = mask credit_card_number
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Steve!
I am using Active Merchant but for some reason my order object couldn't access the display number method. Your method did work nonetheless. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No probs Kenji! It's because it's an instance method of `ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard` not of your model. You can use a callback to update an attribute before saving, then it will be persistently available.

Comment: Good to know. I'll be sure to do that if it's necessary.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a regex approach:

```
x.gsub!(/.(?=....)/, '*')
```

Here's an approach using string indexing:

```
x = '*' * (x.size - 4) + x[-4, 4]
```

Comment: I really like the first one. Thanks!

Comment: I really like the second. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Ruby's `gsub` method and a regular expression to hide some of the numbers in the account number string:

```
hidenumber = "123-123-1234"
hidenumber.gsub(/(\d{3}-\d{3})/,"xxx-xxx")
```